# How to handle React Svg Drag and Drop with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, drag-and-drop, react-hooks

I am trying to implement Drag and Drop on a SVG shape. I succeeded to make it works with using Class Component. Here is the link to the Code Sandbox :  https://codesandbox.io/s/qv81pq1roq

But now I would like to extract this logic by using the new React api with a custom Hook that will be able to add this feature to a functional component. I tried many things but nothing works. Here is my last try :

https://codesandbox.io/s/2x2850vjk0

I am suspecting something with the way I add and remove the event listener... So here are my questions :

Do you think, it is event possible to put this DnD SVG logic to a custom Hook ? If it is, do you have any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/2w0oy6qnvn

There were a number of issues in your hooks example:

1. `setPosition` is different from `setState`. It doesn't do a shallow merge, it replaces the entire object with the new value, so you have to use `Object.assign()` or spread operator to merge with the previous value. Also, the `setPosition()` hook takes a callback value which provides the previous state value as a first parameter if you need to reference it when setting the new value.
2. Unlike in classes, the `handleMouseMove` function is recreated in every render, so `document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)` is no longer referencing the initial `handleMouseMove` value when `document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)` was invoked. The workaround for this is to use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) which creates an object that persists throughout the lifetime of the component, perfect for retaining reference to functions.
3. The event parameter in `handleMouseDown` and the one you reference in `setPosition` aren't the same. Because React uses event pooling and reuses the events, the event in `setPosition` could already be different from the one passed into `handleMouseDown`. The way around this is to get the values of `pageX` and `pageY` first so that within `setPosition` it doesn't need to rely on the event object.

I annotated the code below with the parts which you need to take note of.

```js
const Circle = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState({
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    coords: {},
  });
  
  // Use useRef to create the function once and hold a reference to it.
  const handleMouseMove = React.useRef(e => {
    setPosition(position => {
      const xDiff = position.coords.x - e.pageX;
      const yDiff = position.coords.y - e.pageY;
      return {
        x: position.x - xDiff,
        y: position.y - yDiff,
        coords: {
          x: e.pageX,
          y: e.pageY,
        },
      };
    });
  });

  const handleMouseDown = e => {
    // Save the values of pageX and pageY and use it within setPosition.
    const pageX = e.pageX; 
    const pageY = e.pageY;
    setPosition(position => Object.assign({}, position, {
      coords: {
        x: pageX,
        y: pageY,
      },
    }));
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove.current);
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove.current);
    // Use Object.assign to do a shallow merge so as not to 
    // totally overwrite the other values in state.
    setPosition(position =>
      Object.assign({}, position, {
        coords: {},
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <circle
      cx={position.x}
      cy={position.y}
      r={25}
      fill="black"
      stroke="black"
      strokeWidth="1"
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
    />
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <svg
      style={{
        border: '1px solid green',
        height: '200px',
        width: '100%',
      }}
    >
      <Circle />
    </svg>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yangshun for your very complete response ! I didn't know this way of using React.useRef() could also apply to function and not only dom nodes...very interesting. By curiosity, is it possible to get the reference to a function just by using javascript ? Finally I was able to put all the logic to a custom Hook . Here is the new sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/50n0qoqrzn .  By the way, the new Hook api is really lit !

Comment: Yes you could use plain JS to get the function reference, which was what you did in the class component version. In functions I don't think you can do it with just what you have because functions do not have state/instances and you'll need to store the reference to the function somewhere outside the function component. Glad you're liking the new hook API! I'm liking it too (:

Comment: how can I do the same for zoom behavior?

Comment: Great answer Yangshun! I would add one extra hook to be safe:

useEffect(() => () => document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove.current));

Basically you want to ensure that you remove the event listener from the document in case the component is removed while dragging.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic custom hook I've been using to register drag events on SVG elements.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef } from 'react'

// You may need to edit this to serve your specific use case
function getPos(e) {    
  return {
    x: e.pageX,
    y: e.pageY,
  }
}

// from https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state    
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef()
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value
  })
  return ref.current
}

export function useDrag({ onDrag, onDragStart, onDragEnd }) {
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false)

  const handleMouseMove = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      onDrag(getPos(e))
    }, 
    [onDrag]
  )

  const handleMouseUp = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      onDragEnd(getPos(e))
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
      setIsDragging(false)
    }, 
    [onDragEnd, handleMouseMove]
  )

  const handleMouseDown = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      onDragStart(getPos(e))
      setIsDragging(true)
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
    }, 
    [onDragStart, handleMouseMove]
  )

  const prevMouseMove = usePrevious(handleMouseMove)

  useEffect(
    () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', prevMouseMove);
      if(isDragging) {
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
      }
    },
    [prevMouseMove, handleMouseMove, isDragging]
  )

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (isDragging) {
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp)
      }
      return () => document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp)
    },
    [isDragging, handleMouseUp]
  )

  return handleMouseDown
}
```

Comment: Nathan, why do you use usePrevious() hook and why only for mouseMove but not mouseUp?
BTW, it looks like addEventLister() and removeEventlListener() are called more than once. I reproduced it here:
https://codepen.io/markvital/pen/NWGaeRw